# HTML Trouble Floating Two Images Side-By-Side

Tags: html, image, alignment

Having trouble trying to make two images show side by side, they are not aligned perfectly and I do not know how to fix it,

```
    <article style="width:100%;">
<h1> Repair Services </h1>
<p> We repair computers </p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="float:left">
</article>

<article style=";width:100%;">
<h1> Repair Services </h1>
<p> We repair computers </p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="float:right">
</article>
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Syystole/vfkg8018/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flex layouting

i updated your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vfkg8018/13/

wrap all into div and set class .side-by-side on wrapping div

```
.side-by-side{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<div style="float:left">
    <article style="width:100%;">
        <h1> Repair Services </h1>
        <p> We repair computers </p>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="float:left">
    </article>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <article style="width:100%;">
        <h1> Repair Services </h1>
        <p> We`enter code here` repair computers </p>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="float:right">
    </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may solve your problem :

```
<article  style="width:100%;">
<div style="float:right;width:50%">
    <div style="float:right; margin-left:20px">
        <h1> Repair Services </h1>
        <p> We repair computers </p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    </div>
</div>

<div style="float:right;width:50%">
    <div style="float:right; margin-left:20px">
        <h1> Repair Services </h1>
        <p> We repair computers </p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    </div>
</div></article >
```